# jQuery Validation dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm having a weird problem. Trying to use jQuery Validation to validate a dropdown/select list on my form, but it just won't validate. Not sure why, I've double checked if there is any typo or any syntax error but none. Below is a copy of my code.

Thanks a million!

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        //datepicker script
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            altField: $('#dateHdn'),
            dateFormat: "MM-dd-yy"
        }); //end of datepicker script

        //configure validation here
        $("#addform").validate({
            rules: {
                invacc: { required:true },
                lvlstat: { required: true }

            },
            messages: {
                invacc: "please insert a value",
                lvlstat: "Please choose a status" 
            }
        })// end of validate script

        //dropdown script
        $("#lvlstat").selectmenu({
        });//end of dropdown script});

       </script>
       </head>

<body>
<form id="addform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add Required Values</legend>
        <p>
            <label for="invacc">Inventory Accuracy: </label>
            <input type="text" name="invacc" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="lti">LTI: </label>
            <input type="text" name="lti" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="overtime">Overtime: </label>
            <input type="text" name="overtime" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="datetime">Date: </label>
            <input type="text" name="dtval" id="datepicker" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="lvlstat">Status: </label>
            <select id="lvlstat" name="lvlstat">
                <option value="">Choose an Option</option>
                <option value="1">Certified</option>
                <option value="2">Learner</option>
                <option value="3">Rookie</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p><label for="FileUpload">Image Upload: </label>
        @FileUpload.GetHtml(
        initialNumberOfFiles: 1,
        allowMoreFilesToBeAdded: false,
        includeFormTag: false,
        uploadText: "Upload")
        </p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="buttonSubmit" value="Add" /></p>
        <p><a href="~/main">Return to main page</a></p>

    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: `but it just won't validate` what do you mean by this? like what is expected and what is happening.. Also it will be even better if you can reproduce the issue in a Jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) so that people can give you quick response.

Comment: u have commented the closing brackets before end of script tag

Comment: @Reddy only the dropdown/select box don't validate, other textbox in the form will generate an error if its empty, so everytime I clicked on the submit button with everything else filled except for the  select box it will still go through. I will get try to do it on jsfiddle and link it here.

Comment: @Monasha it's a copy error I made, in my code its correct.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ssxdhuhf/7/ here is the fiddle...

Comment: @Collin your fiddle is not complete.. It has errors, looks like you have not added necessary scripts into the fiddle. Also in your main code you have referenced the validate plugin twice.. .js and .min.js you need to have just one.

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
$("input[name='buttonSubmit']").click(
    function(){
                    if($('#lvlstat').val() == ''){
                alert('dropdown validationg failed');
              return false;
          }
    });
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cyLzyvfm/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check the includes of your script, because it seems that 
you have included the validation jquery script twice (the *original* version and the *minified* version):

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Furthermore, you can check the **browser console** and use the **developer tools** provided by your browser to verify that the script are correctly retrieved and identify possible errors.